# spl_autoload_register - class not found

Tags: php, include

File included (found in included list)
Class 'config' not found

Where is the mistake?  I can't find out where is a problem.

```
<?php

    define(DS,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    final class kernel
    {           
        static private function classLoader($className)
        {                                   
            include 'project'.DS.'system'.DS.$className.'.php';  
        }

        static public function execute()
        {
            spl_autoload_register('self::classLoader');
            $config = new config;  
        } 
    }

?>
```

config.php data:

```
<?php

    class config
    {     
        static public function settings()
        {
           return 'test';  
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: when I have this kind of problem, I add a print statement in the class loader to see what the exact path is that it's trying to load.

Comment: Also, the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` reference is probably unnecessary, since the `include()` function will handle it correctly for any OS if you just use back-slashes.

Comment: the file is included, but the class was not found

Comment: okay, are you *sure* the file was included? What happens if you change it to `require`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

My mistake. FTP client shows the file, but it was clear. Cached copy was with PHP code.